# ReactNative IOS Testflight Firebase MapStateToProps Update Issue

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, promise, testflight

I am having an extremely weird issue where I don't even know where to begin to debug since it only happens when I get the app into test flight.  Basically I am trying to load channels based on geolocation.  Some automatically load and then some are loaded if less than 100 miles from a mountain (lets call these PUBLIC and PRIVATE channels- both of which are in the same list).  I have these 2 firebase calls in my action creator and push them into an array and then call dispatch after.  I have an issue with the FlatList where it loads the PUBLIC channels and only when I scroll do the PRIVATE channels.  There are a bunch of things I have tried including the most common from that specific github issue (flatlist updating) 'removeClippedSubviews={false}', extra data, pure components, etc, but none have worked.

Instead I found a way to get around this (I know it isn't the best, but I just want a solution that works for now) by just setting a timeout and waiting for the channels before dispatching the action:

```
setTimeout(function(){ dispatch(loadPublicChannelsSuccess(data)); }, 10);
```

Unfortunately, now is when the crazy issue comes in.  Basically, this works for debug, release/ everything I have tried with XCode, but when it gets to my device the render method basically sits at a loading indicator until I switch tabs with react navigation.  This makes no sense to me since it doesn't happen always (maybe 80%) of the time, and only in test flight so far.  I had never seen this before setting the timeout either so not really sure where to begin:

```
render() {
    const {loadPublicChannels, loading, publicChannels, checkedInMountain, selectedMountain} = this.props;
    return !loadPublicChannels && publicChannels && !loading 
    ? (
      <MessagePanelPublic publicChannels={publicChannels} selectedMountain={selectedMountain}/>
    ) : (
      <LoadingAnimation />
    );
  }
```

actions

```
export const getUserPublicChannels = () => {
  return (dispatch, state) => {
    dispatch(loadPublicChannels());
    // get all mountains within distance specified
    let mountainsInRange = state().session.mountainsInRange;
    // get the user selected mountain
    let selectedMountain = state().session.selectedMountain;

    // see if the selected mountain is in range to add on additional channels
    let currentMountain;
    mountainsInRange
      ? (currentMountain =
          mountainsInRange.filter(mountain => mountain.id === selectedMountain)
            .length === 1
            ? true
            : false)
      : (currentMountain = false);

    // mountain public channels (don't need to be within distance)
    let currentMountainPublicChannelsRef = FIREBASE_REF_CHANNEL_INFO.child(
      "Public"
    )
      .child(`${selectedMountain}`)
      .child("Public");

    // mountain private channels- only can see if within range (geolocation)
    let currentMountainPrivateChannelsRef = FIREBASE_REF_CHANNEL_INFO.child(
      "Public"
    )
      .child(`${selectedMountain}`)
      .child("Private");

    // get public channels
    return currentMountainPublicChannelsRef
      .orderByChild("key")
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        let publicChannelsToDownload = [];
        snapshot.forEach(channelSnapshot => {
          let channelId = channelSnapshot.key;
          let channelInfo = channelSnapshot.val();
          // add the channel ID to the download list
          publicChannelsToDownload.push({ id: channelId, info: channelInfo });
        });

        // if mountain exists then get private channels/ if in range
        if (currentMountain) {
          currentMountainPrivateChannelsRef
            .orderByChild("key")
            .once("value")
            .then(snapshot => {
              snapshot.forEach(channelSnapshot => {
                let channelId = channelSnapshot.key;
                let channelInfo = channelSnapshot.val();
                publicChannelsToDownload.push({
                  id: channelId,
                  info: channelInfo
                });
              });
            });
        }
        return publicChannelsToDownload;
      })

      .then(data => {
        setTimeout(function(){ dispatch(loadPublicChannelsSuccess(data)); }, 10);

      });
  };
};
```

reducer related to public channels

```
case types.LOAD_PUBLIC_CHANNELS:
  return {
    ...state,
    loadPublicChannels: true
  };

case types.LOAD_PUBLIC_CHANNELS_SUCCESS:
  console.log("PUBLIC");
  console.log(action.publicChannels);
  console.log(action);
  return {
    ...state,
    publicChannels: action.publicChannels,
    loadPublicChannels: false,
    messages: {}
  };

case types.LOAD_PUBLIC_CHANNELS_ERROR:
  return {
    ...state,
    channelsPublicError: action.error,
    loadPublicChannels: false
  };
```

container which calls mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps

```
class MessagePanelPublicContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  // get public and private channels from redux
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserPrivateChannels();
    this.props.loadCurrentUser();
    // this.props.getUserPublicChannels();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.mountainsInRange && prevProps.mountainsInRange !== this.props.mountainsInRange || prevProps.selectedMountain !== this.props.selectedMountain) {
      this.props.getUserPublicChannels();
    }
  }

  lessThan12HourAgo = (date) => {
    return moment(date).isAfter(moment().subtract(12, 'hours'));
  }

  render() {
    const {loadPublicChannels, loading, publicChannels, checkedInMountain, selectedMountain} = this.props;
    return !loadPublicChannels && publicChannels && !loading 
    ? (
      <MessagePanelPublic publicChannels={publicChannels} selectedMountain={selectedMountain}/>
    ) : (
      <LoadingAnimation />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
  publicChannels: state.chat.publicChannels,
  loadPublicChannels: state.chat.loadPublicChannels,
  currentUser: state.chat.currentUser,
  loading: state.chat.loadCurrentUser,
  mountainsInRange: state.session.mountainsInRange,
  selectedMountain: state.session.selectedMountain,
};
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loadCurrentUser,
  getUserPublicChannels,
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MessagePanelPublicContainer);
```

component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, ImageComponent } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { ListItem, Icon, Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";
import styles from "./Styles";
import moment from 'moment';
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';
class MessagePanelPublicComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    // rendering all public channels
    const renderPublicChannels = ({ item }) => {
      return (
        <ListItem
          leftAvatar={{
            source: { uri: item.info.ChannelPicture },
            rounded: false,
            overlayContainerStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" },
            ImageComponent: FastImage
          }}
          title={item.info.Name}
          titleStyle={styles.title}
          chevron={true}
          bottomDivider={true}
          id={item.Name}
          containerStyle={styles.listItemStyle}
        />
      );
    };

    const renderText = () => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.extraTextContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.extraText}>
            Get within 100 miles from resort or select a closer resort to see more channels...
          </Text>
          <Icon
            name="map-marker"
            type="font-awesome"
            size={40}
            iconStyle={styles.extraIcon}
          />
        </View>
      );
    };


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.channelList}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.props.publicChannels}
            renderItem={renderPublicChannels}
            // keyExtractor={item => item.Name}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            extraData={this.props.publicChannels}
            removeClippedSubviews={false}
          />
          {this.props.publicChannels.length < 3 ? renderText() : null}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```